# Unable to grab expected result from a site issuing post requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, http-post

I'm trying to fetch some json response from a [webpage](http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp) using the script below. Here are the steps to populate the result in that site. Click on the ***AGREE*** button located at the bottom of this [webpage](http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp) and then on the ***EDIT SEARCH*** button and finally on ***SHOW RESULTS*** button without changing anything.

I've tried like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp'
post_url = 'http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp'

payload = {
    'postData': {'Keywords':[]},
    'ticker': '',
    'startDate': '',
    'endDate': '',
    'showResultsAs': 'B',
    'debtOrAssetClass': '1,2',
    'spdsType': ''
}

payload_second = {
    'count': '20',
    'searchtype': 'B',
    'query': {"Keywords":[{"Name":"debtOrAssetClass","Value":"3,6"},{"Name":"showResultsAs","Value":"B"}]},
    'sortfield': 'issuerName',
    'sorttype': '1',
    'start': '0',
    'curPage': '1'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/UserAgreement.jsp'
    r = s.post(url,json=payload)
    s.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = r.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers']
    s.headers['cf-request-id'] = r.headers['cf-request-id']
    s.headers['CF-RAY'] = r.headers['CF-RAY']
    s.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
    s.headers['Origin'] = 'http://finra-markets.morningstar.com'
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp'
    r = s.post(post_url,json=payload_second)
    print(r.content)
```

This is the result I get when I run the script above:

```
b'\n\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n\n\n{}'
```

> How can I make the script populate expected result from that site?

P.S. I do not wish to go for selenium to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

The response for `http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp` doesn't contain the search results. It must be fetching the data asynchronously.

An easy way to find out which network requests returned the search results, is to search the requests for one of the search results using Firefox's [Dev Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list):

[image: The search button]

[image: Searching the requests]

To convert the HTTP request to a Python request, I copy the request as a CURL code method from Firefox, import it into Postman and then export it as a Python code (a little long-winded (and lazy) I know!):

[image: Copy request as CURL]

[image: Import button in Postman]

[image: Import CURL request in Postman]

[image: The 'code' button in Postman]

[image: The dropdown to select the code language in Postman]

All this leads to the following code:

```
import requests

url = "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp"

payload = "count=20&searchtype=B&query=%7B%22Keywords%22%3A%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22debtOrAssetClass%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%223%2C6%22%7D%2C%7B%22Name%22%3A%22showResultsAs%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22B%22%7D%5D%7D&sortfield=issuerName&sorttype=1&start=0&curPage=1"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': "...",
    'Accept': "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest",
    'Origin': "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com",
    'DNT': "1",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'Referer': "http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Results.jsp",
    'Cookie': "...",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

The response wasn't 100% JSON. So I just stripped away the outer whitespace and `{B:..}` part:

```
>>> text = response.text.strip()[3:-1]
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads(text)
>>> data['Columns'][0]                                                                                                             
{'moodyRating': {'ratingText': '', 'ratingNumber': 0},
 'fitchRating': {'ratingText': None, 'ratingNumber': None},
 'standardAndPoorRating': {'ratingText': '', 'ratingNumber': 0},
```

Comment: The only reason I tried to send two subsequent post requests is because I wanted to reuse the cookies. However. your script works, if I use hardcoded cookies within the headers.

Comment: @robots.txt you can still do that of course, but just be sure to call http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp to get the results :)